# Turning a database result printout of a JPEG name into a HTML link that opens in a new tab?

Tags: php, html, sql, loops

I am creating a PHP page where the page prints out the whole of a database I have of meat packaging. I am printing the results of the database in order of their shape (Rectangular, Oval, Square, Insert). I can happily get the database to print out the results but what I want to do for one of the columns is change the result that is printed into a HTML link.

This column is 'Imagename', it prints the name of a JPEG that is stored on the server. I want it so that when the result for 'Imagename' is printed with the JPEG on the side it isn't text but actually a link to a new tab that displays the picture for the user to view.

Here is my current PHP that loops through the database printing it in a table:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "horizon1", "");
mysql_select_db("horizon1_delyn", $con);

if ( ! $con)
{
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

$rectangular = mysql_query("SELECT toolcode, description, traysize, imagename FROM range WHERE trayshape ='rectangular' ORDER BY traysize");
$oval        = mysql_query("SELECT toolcode, description, traysize, imagename FROM range WHERE trayshape ='oval' ORDER BY traysize");
$square      = mysql_query("SELECT toolcode, description, traysize, imagename FROM range WHERE trayshape ='square' ORDER BY traysize");
$insert      = mysql_query("SELECT toolcode, description, traysize, imagename FROM range WHERE trayshape ='insert' ORDER BY traysize");

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($rectangular);

echo "<table width='97%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr>";


//*RECTANGULAR*//

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++)
{
  $field = mysql_fetch_field($rectangular);
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E8CF24' style='font-family: arial;font-size: 12px;'>{$field->name}</td>";
}

echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rectangular))
{
  echo "<tr>";

  foreach ($row as $cell)
    echo "<td style='font-family: arial;font-size:12px'>$cell</td>";
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($rectangular);


//* OVAL *// 

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++)
{
  $field = mysql_fetch_field($oval);
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E8CF24' style='font-family: arial;font-size: 12px'>{$field->name}</td>";
}

echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($oval))
{
  echo "<tr>";

  foreach ($row as $cell)
    echo "<td style='font-family: arial;font-size:12px'>$cell</td>";

  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($oval);


//* SQUARE *// 

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++)
{
  $field = mysql_fetch_field($square);
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E8CF24' style='font-family: arial;font-size: 12px'>{$field->name}</td>";
}

echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($square))
{
  echo "<tr>";

  foreach ($row as $cell)
    echo "<td style='font-family: arial;font-size:12px'>$cell</td>";

  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($square);


//* INSERT *// 

for ($i = 0; $i < $fields_num; $i++)
{
  $field = mysql_fetch_field($insert);
  echo "<td bgcolor='#E8CF24' style='font-family: arial;font-size: 12px'>{$field->name}</td>";
}

echo "</tr>\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($insert))
{
  echo "<tr>";

  foreach ($row as $cell)
    echo "<td style='font-family: arial;font-size:12px'>$cell</td>";

  echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($insert);

?>
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could in a sense isolate the 'Imagename' column to make the images clickable? Thanks for your help?

Comment: Do you have the .sql code to recreate the database table? Just for save time.

Comment: I do but I want to limit the database from 14 columns down to only the ones I have above. So I just quickly created the above tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, they are going to rip you to shreds for not escaping, but I'll let someone else tell you off for that.

At the minute you are outputting everything from the table in one go, you need to split it up, so instead of

```
echo "<td style='font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;'>{$cell}</td>";
```

You will want something like

```
echo '<td style="font-family: arial;font-size:12px">' . $cell['toolcode'] . '<a href=' . $cell['imagename'] . ' target="_blank">' . $cell['imagename'] . '</a></td>';
```

You need to echo the values individually, and then wrap an `<a>` tag around the hyperlink, with a href

Comment: The above only echos the name of each column, it doesn't actually display any data. So editing the above code wouldn't do anything. I would need to echo the below $cell code, not the one you suggested. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I added `target="_blank"` for the 'new tab/window' request

Comment: The values that get returned seem to be strange text, which I have no idea where it came from haha.

Comment: @LiamHorizon The example I used I printed out your [toolcode] and [imagename] values

Comment: Hmm, i get random letters and numbers some that are hyperlinked and others that aren't. 

toolcode description traysize imagename
ii SS 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii SS 11 ii
ii PP 11 ii
ii SS 11 ii
ii LL 11 ii
ii CC 11 ii
ii TT 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii  11 ii
ii 11 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii DD 11 ii
ii 44 11 ii
ii 22 11 ii
ii MM 11 ii

Comment: @LiamHorizon I have no clue what that means lmao, is nothing like that in your database?

Comment: Me either! Haha! That is just what appears. No nothing like this is in the database. By my understanding, the code you wrote should work. But maybe because every column needs to be filled?

Comment: @LiamHorizon Can you get a screenshot of what is in the database (predicted output) and what is actually output (including its formatting with the hyperlinks)

Comment: @LiamHorizon I'm goin to try and work with just the rectangular table for now, try this:

Edit: I'm moving to pastebin, comments are horrible

Comment: @Andy So what does this currently do? It works, yes. But only does the same thing currently. If the Rectangular table works then the rest will be easy.

Comment: @LiamHorizon Ok, try this: http://pastebin.com/YT8mjPsD . You didn't "select" trayshape, by the way, if that matters. I swapped it round, each time through the loop it does one row, and prints out each item into its own TD

Comment: I still get the random letters and junk. I have no idea why!

Comment: This might sound stupid but do a really simple query, make sure you are a) hitting a database and b) hitting the right database

Comment: Yeah indeed. Because when the code I used before with just getting all of the $cell to printout it prints out the whole database and the connection is to the correct database.

Comment: I don't really know what to suggest, you shouldn't print out an entire database in one go if you want semantic HTMl and stuff, and then obviously you can't embed `<a>` tags if you do.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I just really can't wrap my head around where these random numbers and letters are coming from, and why your code isn't working. It really should. And there doesn't seem to be any connection issues with the database. Very odd. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Give me a shout if you find out how, I'm no expert in PHP/MySQL but I've never seen anything remotely similar